# Passing an object to a method results in an object with no values?

Tags: c#, object, methods, mono, monodevelop

I am new to C# and I'm having a strange problem when I try to pass an object from one method into another. My problem is when I call for a value from the object in the second method it returns nothing.

Please forgive me if something like this has been asked before. All of my efforts have turned up hundreds of duplicate questions about the difference between normal operation and passing an object reference instead of simply passing the object. (I tried both ways and neither seem to work.)

Simply put, I couldn't find anything explaining why the value of my object would be empty when it gets passed to another method.

I've included an excerpt of how my classes are defined and what their methods do. I also included how this issue is implemented in my project. Finally, I've posted the output so you can see what I'm talking about (because I don't know enough to explain the problem very well, and it seems proper to show you the symptom first-hand).

How can I properly pass an object to another function? (ie: What am I doing wrong?)

### Class Definitions:

```
// 'class Expression' stores an expression in postfix notation
// and does all kinds of sweet math stuffs to it:
public class Expresssion
{
    public List<string> Value;

    public Expression (List<string> postfix_input)
    {
        Value = postfix_input;
    }
    //(...)
}

// 'class Terp' is a static class designed to convert user-readable
// infix expressions into tokenized lists in postfix notation so I
// can more easily do math.
public static class Terp
{
    public static List<string> ToPostfix (string infix_input)
    {
        //{"1+2"} >> {"1","2","+"}
        return postfix_output;
    }
    public static string ToInfix (List<string> postfix_input)
    {
        //{"1","2","+"} >> {"1+2"}
        return infix_output;
    }
    public static string CompileString (List<string> tokens_input)
    {
        //{"1","2","+"} >> {"12+"}
        return string_output;
    }
    //(...)
}
```

### Implementation:

```
public static void StepOne (string command, string user_input)
{
    // NOTE: 'command' and 'user_input' are both provided by parsing the
    // user's input via a graphical interface (I'm simplifying here because
    // I don't want this to get cluttered with regex stuff).

    // Creating the Expression instance:
    Expression target_expr = new Expression(Terp.ToPostfix(user_input));

    // Setting up console messages to make sure the input is there:
    Console.WriteLine("Command: '" + command + "'");
    Console.WriteLine("Expression: '" + Terp.CompileString(target_expr.Value) + "'");

    // Passing 'Expression' object into 'StepTwo()':
    StepTwo(command, target_expr);
}


static void StepTwo (string command, Expression target_expr)
{
    // Making sure everything made it through the Stargate alright:
    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("Command: '" + command + "'");
    Console.WriteLine("Expression: '" + Terp.CompileString(target_expr.Value) + "'");
}
```

### Output:

```
Command: 'dd'
Expression: '12+'
------------------------------
Command: 'dd'
Expression: ''
```

As a final note, the 'Terp' class checks out. So does the 'Expression' class. Both behave splendidly in all other situations. After passing my object to `StepTwo()`, if I try to call `target_expr.Value[0]` my program throws an "argument out of range" exception.

Again, if anyone can explain what is wrong here I'd really appreciate it. I'm VERY new to C#, and figuring this one out has me pretty stumped.

Thanks in advance!

### Update:

Sorry for the missing method. Here's the code for `CompileString()`:

```
public static string CompileString (List<string> tokens_input)
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        foreach (string token in tokens_input)
        {
            str = str + token;
        }
    return str;
    }
```

I don't see how that would change the value for `target_expr`, but I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: `CompileString()` method doesn't add any `,` to the string. How did you get the return value like `1,2,+` ?

Comment: Woops! Sorry, I screwed up on copying. I've fiddled since then. Let me update.

Comment: Do you think you can produce a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit it into your question, or make a [fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/) with it? I fail to see how and why your problem is occuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I totally solved my problem...

I completely misunderstood how objects are handled in C#. I also didn't realize (though it's obvious to me now) a `List<>` is an *object* in C# instead of a simple data type (like it is with python).

Answers (as always) could be found in documentation and in good articles about best practices (once I knew what to look for):

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx
- http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/cloning072002.htm

The problem was in my methods `ToInfix()` and `ToPostfix()`. (Actually, the problem was with *every method* in the `Terp` class that handles conversion.)

**In short, I didn't realize that `target_expr.Value` was a reference to a list *object*. I also didn't realize that when I pass that object to a method, it passes a *reference to the object* (not a copy of its value) and that any changes effect the original object.**

Long story short, one of the methods in `Terp` "eats" the `postfix_input` list while it's converting from one form to the next. This garbled `target_expr.Value`.

**The solution was simple. When passing a `List<>` object to `ToInfix()`, I make a token-for-token copy before passing it on to any of the private methods in `Terp`:**

```
public static string ToInfix (List<string> postfix_input)
{
    // Make a one-to-one copy of a list:
    List<string> postfix_copy = new List<string>();
    foreach (string token in postfix_input)
    {
        postfix_copy.Add(token);
    }
    // Then do stuff...
    //(...)
}
```

This fix makes everything behave as expected.

Now that I know this is how objects work, I will go through and clean up `Terp` to make sure this is handled correctly. Thanks especially to @Shaharyar, since looking at his example got me on track, and @AlexD got me looking in the right place.

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I've compiled your code and it works perfectly. I put the breakpoints and checked all values at every single step and every thing was fine.

Here is the code. Try to execute it:

**Your Code:**

```
// 'class Expression' stores an expression in postfix notation
// and does all kinds of sweet math stuffs to it:
public class Expression
{
    public List<string> Value;

    public Expression(List<string> postfix_input)
    {
        Value = postfix_input;
    }
}

// 'class Terp' is a static class designed to convert user-readable
// infix expressions into tokenized lists in postfix notation so I
// can more easily do math.
public static class Terp
{
    public static List<string> ToPostfix(string infix_input)
    {
        List<string> postfix_output = new List<string>();
        foreach (char c in infix_input)
        {
            postfix_output.Add(c.ToString());
        }
        //{"1+2"} >> {"1","2","+"}
        return postfix_output;
    }
    public static string ToInfix(List<string> postfix_input)
    {
        string infix_output = String.Empty;
        //{"1","2","+"} >> {"1+2"}
        return infix_output;
    }
    public static string CompileString(List<string> tokens_input)
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        foreach (string token in tokens_input)
        {
            str = str + token;
        }
        //{"1","2","+"} >> {"1,2,+"}
        return str;
    }
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StepOne("dd", "12+");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void StepOne(string command, string user_input)
{
    // NOTE: 'command' and 'user_input' are both provided by parsing the
    // user's input via a graphical interface (I'm simplifying here because
    // I don't want this to get cluttered with regex stuff).

    // Creating the Expression instance:
    Expression target_expr = new Expression(Terp.ToPostfix(user_input));

    // Setting up console messages to make sure the input is there:
    Console.WriteLine("Command: '" + command + "'");
    Console.WriteLine("Expression: '" + Terp.CompileString(target_expr.Value) + "'");

    // Passing 'Expression' object into 'StepTwo()':
    StepTwo(command, target_expr);
}

static void StepTwo(string command, Expression target_expr)
{
    // Making sure everything made it through the Stargate alright:
    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("Command: '" + command + "'");
    Console.WriteLine("Expression: '" + Terp.CompileString(target_expr.Value) + "'");
}
```

**Output:**

```
Command: 'dd'
Expression: '12+'
------------------------------
Command: 'dd'
Expression: '12+'
```

**Debugging:**

**In Step 1:**

Value of `target_expr` before going into the method `Step 2`.

[image]

**In Step 2:**

Value of `target_expr` in the method `Step 2`.

[image]

The reference is fine. Now try to match the code, may be you are missing something.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do this! Looking at your answer helped me point in the right direction. My problem was that I was passing a `List<>` thinking it made a copy, when in fact it was passing a reference to `target_expr.Value` and changing that value. Turns out the bad code wasn't even in my example, it was in a completely different method within `Terp`.

Comment: You need to learn the difference between `Value type` and `Reference type` objects. I am glad it helped you. As you posted your complete answer, also choose it as answer to properly finish a question to answer process of StackOverFlow.

Comment: I'll mark it as soon as stackoverflow lets me. Apparently I have another 23 hours :/